# SQL Server null table join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have two tables one of it is LEAGUE, another is MATCH , in MATCH table there is a column as refLeague  now I want to get total matches of week

For example

```
Id TotalMatches
-- ------------
1   12
2    0
3    6
```

If there is no match, I want to write 0 as table

```
 SELECT l.Id ,COUNT(m.Id) as TotalMatches 
 FROM LEAGUE l
 LEFT JOIN MATCH m ON l.Id = m.refLeauge
 WHERE 
     m.MatchDate >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 1, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7 + 1, 0) 
     AND m.MatchDate < DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -6, GETDATE())/7 * 7 + 1, 0) 
     AND l.refSport = 1
 GROUP BY l.Id
```

I wrote this query but it is not giving any result due to no rows in Match table, but it must be written 0

Example

```
Id TotalMatches
-- ------------
 1      0
 2      0
 3      0
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the right table filters to `ON` condition

Non matching records will have `NULL` values in `m.MatchDate` which will be filtered by the condition in `Where` clause . Implicitly it will be converted to `INNER JOIN`. So the condition should be moved to `ON` clause which tells what are the records to be joined with `LEAGUE` instead of filtering the result

```
SELECT l.id, 
       Count(m.id) AS TotalMatches 
FROM   league l 
       LEFT JOIN match m 
              ON l.id = m.refleauge 
                 AND m.matchdate >= Dateadd(dd, Datediff(dd, 1, Getdate()) / 7 * 7 + 1, 0) 
                 AND m.matchdate < Dateadd(dd, Datediff(dd, -6, Getdate()) / 7 * 7 + 1, 0) 
WHERE  l.refsport = 1 
GROUP  BY l.id
```

Answer (score 2):

The where is breaking the left join

```
 SELECT l.Id, COUNT(m.Id) as TotalMatches 
 FROM LEAGUE l
 LEFT JOIN MATCH m 
   ON l.Id = m.refLeauge
  and m.MatchDate >= dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 1, getdate()) / 7 * 7 + 1,0) 
  AND m.MatchDate <  dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,-6, getdate()) / 7 * 7 + 1,0) 
 where l.refSport=1
 GROUP BY l.Id
```

/ 7 * 7 = 1

When I started this answer the other answer was not yet posted