# SQL Server: Grouping on one field in a joined table while retaining the NULL results

Tags: sql-server, group-by, left-join

I am trying to join 2 tables and restrict the output of the right hand table based on the field ob.[type] at first i struggled to retain the NULL values of the left join but then I read this question

[SQL Server null table join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862219/sql-server-null-table-join)

and moved my WHERE condition to the ON condition.

This is the code I am now using

```
SELECT  

CASE
WHEN
datepart(MM,ib.[Start Time]) > 3 
and
datepart(MM,ib.[Start Time]) < 11
THEN
dateadd(hh,1,ib.[Start Time])
ELSE ib.[Start Time]  
END as [Start Time]

,ib.[reference]



      ,[Charged Op. (sec)]

       ,ob.[Reference]
     ,ob.Duration


  FROM [iPR].[dbo].[InboundCallsView] ib
  left join
  [iPR].[dbo].[OutboundCallStatus] ob
  on ib.Reference = ob.Reference
  and ob.[type] = 'Outbound call'
  and

CASE
WHEN
datepart(MM,ib.[Start Time]) > 3 
and
datepart(MM,ib.[Start Time]) < 11
THEN
dateadd(hh,1,ib.[Start Time])
ELSE ib.[Start Time]  
END

Between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-02'

and
  ib.[account] in 

  (SELECT [accountno] 

  from idata3.dbo.[N242316])


  where 

  ib.[type] = 'normal operator call'

-- and ob.[type] = 'Outbound call'

and
  ib.[account] in 

  (SELECT [accountno] 

  from idata3.dbo.[N242316])


and

CASE
WHEN
datepart(MM,ib.[Start Time]) > 3 
and
datepart(MM,ib.[Start Time]) < 11
THEN
dateadd(hh,1,ib.[Start Time])
ELSE ib.[Start Time]  
END

Between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-02'


  order by ib.[Start Time]
```

and it creates this result

```
+---------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
|     Start Time      | reference | Charged Op. (sec) | Reference | Duration |
+---------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
| 01/12/2019 04:14:15 | W9DR4PBW  |               324 | W9DR4PBW  | 68       |
| 01/12/2019 04:29:12 | QX3652QA  |                37 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 08:07:11 | LEB4EP4X  |               614 | LEB4EP4X  | 74       |
| 01/12/2019 08:38:15 | W7CRW7M7  |                39 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 08:58:25 | G976V9Q7  |               242 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 09:12:55 | CTTGVRWK  |                29 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 09:20:29 | JRY77JSQ  |               244 | JRY77JSQ  | 6        |
| 01/12/2019 09:20:29 | JRY77JSQ  |               244 | JRY77JSQ  | 5        |
| 01/12/2019 09:20:29 | JRY77JSQ  |               244 | JRY77JSQ  | 5        |
| 01/12/2019 10:04:42 | 8M47UYWQ  |               285 | 8M47UYWQ  | 88       |
| 01/12/2019 11:35:18 | A6YVL5TW  |                19 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 12:17:23 | A86ERNVX  |                13 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 12:27:15 | GWQ8442D  |                47 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 13:10:22 | VVLXJU44  |               122 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 13:26:04 | 8RL23TF6  |                20 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 13:47:54 | SAY6LZ7T  |               172 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 14:38:37 | J7QBPPGV  |               158 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 18:25:29 | PKU4EB5X  |                10 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 20:57:50 | JDK6WAF6  |                 8 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 20:58:28 | 9KYMCJ8J  |                29 | NULL      | NULL     |
+---------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
```

Which is almost perfect. However it returns 20 rows but I only want to return 18. The reference JRY77JSQ has only 1 inbound call but 3 outbound calls. What I want to do is SUM the 6, 6, and 5 second duration of the 3 outbound calls and have that as the only row with the JRY77JSQ reference. ie

```
+---------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
|     Start Time      | reference | Charged Op. (sec) | Reference | Duration |
+---------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
| 01/12/2019 04:14:15 | W9DR4PBW  |               324 | W9DR4PBW  | 68       |
| 01/12/2019 04:29:12 | QX3652QA  |                37 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 08:07:11 | LEB4EP4X  |               614 | LEB4EP4X  | 74       |
| 01/12/2019 08:38:15 | W7CRW7M7  |                39 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 08:58:25 | G976V9Q7  |               242 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 09:12:55 | CTTGVRWK  |                29 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 09:20:29 | JRY77JSQ  |               244 | JRY77JSQ  | 16       |
| 01/12/2019 10:04:42 | 8M47UYWQ  |               285 | 8M47UYWQ  | 88       |
| 01/12/2019 11:35:18 | A6YVL5TW  |                19 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 12:17:23 | A86ERNVX  |                13 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 12:27:15 | GWQ8442D  |                47 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 13:10:22 | VVLXJU44  |               122 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 13:26:04 | 8RL23TF6  |                20 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 13:47:54 | SAY6LZ7T  |               172 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 14:38:37 | J7QBPPGV  |               158 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 18:25:29 | PKU4EB5X  |                10 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 20:57:50 | JDK6WAF6  |                 8 | NULL      | NULL     |
| 01/12/2019 20:58:28 | 9KYMCJ8J  |                29 | NULL      | NULL     |
+---------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
```

What I tried to do was replace each column signifier with MAX([column]) except ob.[duration] which I replaced with SUM(ob.[duration]). Unfortunaltey this brought me back to my original problem where the NULLs vanished and I was left with only the 4 rows that had information from the  [iPR].[dbo].[OutboundCallStatus] table. How do I group while retaining the NULLs?

Comment: Show us the query you use when you had a `SUM`. I can't see any reason why that would remove `NULL`s from the data set.

Comment: *Side note: There's no need for the clause `ib.[account] IN (SELECT [accountno] FROM idata3.dbo.[N242316])` to be in both the `WHERE` and `ON`. If it's in the `WHERE`, then you can remove it from your `ON`.*

Comment: I also suggest starting to make *good* use of whitespace and linebreaks. Your code has a huge overuse of line breaks, but very little whitespace; making it very difficult to follow. You could easily compress the 80~ lines of code you have into [20~](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=474ffce46585fc6ff30b3e1b3b50e68d) and make it far more readable.

Comment: You don't clearly describe or illustrate what you want this query to do. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. PS Please format code reasonably. Please less data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using group by and sum. Give the following query a try:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN datepart(MM,ib.[Start Time]) > 3 and datepart(MM,ib.[Start Time]) < 11 THEN dateadd(hh,1,ib.[Start Time])
                ELSE ib.[Start Time] END as [Start Time]
        ,ib.[reference]
        ,[Charged Op. (sec)]
        ,ob.[Reference]  
        ,Sum(ob.Duration) as Duration
FROM [iPR].[dbo].[InboundCallsView] ib
left join [iPR].[dbo].[OutboundCallStatus] ob
          on ib.Reference = ob.Reference and ob.[type] = 'Outbound call'    
where ib.[type] = 'normal operator call' and
        CASE WHEN datepart(MM,ib.[Start Time]) > 3 and datepart(MM,ib.[Start Time]) < 11 THEN dateadd(hh,1,ib.[Start Time])
                            ELSE ib.[Start Time] END Between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-02'
            and ib.[account] in (SELECT [accountno] 
                             from idata3.dbo.[N242316])  
Group by CASE WHEN datepart(MM,ib.[Start Time]) > 3 and datepart(MM,ib.[Start Time]) < 11 THEN dateadd(hh,1,ib.[Start Time])
                ELSE ib.[Start Time] END 
        ,ib.[reference]
        ,[Charged Op. (sec)]
        ,ob.[Reference]     
order by ib.[Start Time]
```